# what does format(a, str(b)) mean?

Tags: python

I'm doing my assignment making calendar-month program and there are some codes I don't get.

the program says,

```
current_col = 1
column_width = 4
blank_char = ' '
blank_column = format(blank_char, str(column_width))
```

and I've never learned about format function in this style

What does `format(blank_char, str(4))` mean?

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format) for the format function, which turns objects into strings. The second argument is passed as a string in this [mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec), which says how to format the value.

But in your case, it's trivial, because the format specification string is just `"4"`, which specifies the width (of the result).